# Why charge injection happens

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, charge

When a MOSFET switch is turned off and goes from sample mode to hold mode, the channel charge exits between the source and drain terminals.

My confusion is, why can't some of the charge go back into the bulk instead of source/drain? I was taught that when a MOSCAP is charged and goes from depletion to inversion, the electrons that form the inversion layer are drawn from the bulk. Is this actually not the case? Does this mean that whenever a MOSFET is turned on, in general it'll draw current through its source and drain to form its inversion layer?

Comment: Some amount of charge has to flow through the source and drain terminals when turning on due to the gate-drain and gate-source capacitances. There's also source-to-bulk and drain-to-bulk capacitances. Could it just be that there are multiple charge storage paths involved and when turning off they go back to where they came from?